# Android Studio Libgdx Animation

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

I am trying to do an animation whenever my character jumps. It works in the following way: when I jump, I first draw the animation of my char. If it is finished, I start modifying his position and also draw another texture, for the inAir moment. The problem is that the animation runs instantly (I tried putting the speed 1 frame per second,but it still runs instantly) and the character jumps before the animation is done. I suspect it considers it finished before it actually finishes. This is how I check if the animation is finished: first I check if the animation start (the jump button is pressed) and then I have an if condition like this:

```
    if (animationStarted && rightJumpAnim.isAnimationFinished(System.currentTimeMillis()))
{
    animationStarted = false;
    animationFinished = true;
    timePassed1 = 0;
}
```

After this, I put animationFinished to false when he touches the ground again. Any advice?

P.S. here is the code for running the jumpAnimation:

```
if (toDrawJumpRight1 == true) {
                    animationStarted = true;
                    timePassed1 += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
                    spriteBatch.draw(rightJumpAnim.getKeyFrame(timePassed1, false), posX + cameraX, posY + cameraY, sizeX, sizeY);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem should be in the very first line you provided to us:

```
if (animationStarted && rightJumpAnim.isAnimationFinished(System.currentTimeMillis()))
```

The argument you must pass is the *STATETIME* of the animation.

```
if (animationStarted && rightJumpAnim.isAnimationFinished(timePassed1))
```

Edit:
Some more Informations to this problem:

You say you want 1 frame stay 1 Second.
Now we say, you have approx 5 frames.
5frames * 1 second = 5seconds for finish

so if statetime is over 5 seconds, your animation is played ONE time (is finished)
Animation.isAnimationFinished(float stateTime) checks now, if the current stateTime from your animation is higher than the 5 seconds.

System.currentTimeMillis is at this moment: 
1440618906341

now.. whats bigger?

Have a nice Evening (I recommend using TimeUtils.millis instead of System.currentTimeMillis, guess it's optimated, fo' sure.)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I understand my mistake. Good evening, too!